# How can I access a value obtained at runtime in primitives npos elections?

Tags: pallet, rust, runtime, primitive

I want to change the weight/score of targets on the basis of values got during runtime, in my research I found the score of a target is being calculated in `primitives/npos-elections/phragmen.rs` in `fn seq_phragmen_core` by adding something in `let temp = Rational128::from(temp_n.saturating_add(something), temp_d);`, the code snippet of the same is below.

> ```
>  // loop 2: increment score
>       for voter in &voters {
>           for edge in &voter.edges {
>               let mut candidate = edge.candidate.borrow_mut();
>               if !candidate.elected && !candidate.approval_stake.is_zero() {
>                   let temp_n = multiply_by_rational(
>                       voter.load.n(),
>                       voter.budget,
>                       candidate.approval_stake,
>                   )
>                   .unwrap_or(Bounded::max_value());
>                   let temp_d = voter.load.d();
>                   let temp = Rational128::from(temp_n.saturating_add(something), temp_d);
>                   candidate.score = candidate.score.lazy_saturating_add(temp);
>               }
>           }
>       }
> ```

I found the inputs in the function are coming from `staking->targets`, so i want to know how do i add something to the score in `phragmen.rs` after getting something during runtime.

The one solution that I thought was to add somthing as a field in `pub struct Candidate<AccountId>`, and add it as  `let temp = Rational128::from(temp_n.saturating_add(candidate.something), temp_d);`, but was unable to  get the value of something during.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to implement a custom election algorithm here, and the easiest thing to do is to just implement it as a brand new function (or set of functions).

Then, if you want to use it in the runtime, alongside the staking pallet, all you have to do is implement [`trait NpoSolver`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_election_provider_support/trait.NposSolver.html) for your new implementation.

As an example, the default Phragmen algorithm is used in the runtime not directly, but instead as an implementation of the aforementioned trait. For example, you would do something like:

```rust
pub struct CustomElection<AccountId>(sp_std::marker::PhantomData<(AccountId)>);

impl<AccountId> NposSolver for CustomElection<AccountId>
{
    type AccountId = AccountId;
    type Accuracy = Perbill;
    type Error = ();
    fn solve(
        winners: usize,
        targets: Vec<Self::AccountId>,
        voters: Vec<(Self::AccountId, VoteWeight, impl IntoIterator<Item = Self::AccountId>)>,
    ) -> Result<ElectionResult<Self::AccountId, Self::Accuracy>, Self::Error> {
        // your custom algorithm, similar to seq-phragmen. 
    }
}
```